# Modified BPMF in PyMC3 using `LKJCorr` priors: PositiveDefiniteError using `NUTS`

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc, mcmc, pymc3

I previously implemented the original [Bayesian Probabilistic Matrix Factorization (BPMF)](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~amnih/papers/bpmf.pdf) model in `pymc3`. [See my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29736966/bayesian-probabilistic-matrix-factorization-bpmf-with-pymc3-positivedefinitee) for reference, data source, and problem setup. Per the answer to that question from @twiecki, I've implemented a variation of the model using `LKJCorr` priors for the correlation matrices and uniform priors for the standard deviations. In the original model, the covariance matrices are drawn from Wishart distributions, but due to current limitations of `pymc3`, the Wishart distribution cannot be sampled from properly. [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/101408/46800) to a loosely related question provides a succinct explanation for the choice of `LKJCorr` priors. The new model is below.

```
import pymc3 as pm
import numpy as np
import theano.tensor as t


n, m = train.shape
dim = 10  # dimensionality
beta_0 = 1  # scaling factor for lambdas; unclear on its use
alpha = 2  # fixed precision for likelihood function
std = .05  # how much noise to use for model initialization

# We will use separate priors for sigma and correlation matrix.
# In order to convert the upper triangular correlation values to a
# complete correlation matrix, we need to construct an index matrix:
n_elem = dim * (dim - 1) / 2
tri_index = np.zeros([dim, dim], dtype=int)
tri_index[np.triu_indices(dim, k=1)] = np.arange(n_elem)
tri_index[np.triu_indices(dim, k=1)[::-1]] = np.arange(n_elem)

logging.info('building the BPMF model')
with pm.Model() as bpmf:
    # Specify user feature matrix
    sigma_u = pm.Uniform('sigma_u', shape=dim)
    corr_triangle_u = pm.LKJCorr(
        'corr_u', n=1, p=dim,
        testval=np.random.randn(n_elem) * std)

    corr_matrix_u = corr_triangle_u[tri_index]
    corr_matrix_u = t.fill_diagonal(corr_matrix_u, 1)
    cov_matrix_u = t.diag(sigma_u).dot(corr_matrix_u.dot(t.diag(sigma_u)))
    lambda_u = t.nlinalg.matrix_inverse(cov_matrix_u)

    mu_u = pm.Normal(
        'mu_u', mu=0, tau=beta_0 * lambda_u, shape=dim,
         testval=np.random.randn(dim) * std)
    U = pm.MvNormal(
        'U', mu=mu_u, tau=lambda_u,
        shape=(n, dim), testval=np.random.randn(n, dim) * std)

    # Specify item feature matrix
    sigma_v = pm.Uniform('sigma_v', shape=dim)
    corr_triangle_v = pm.LKJCorr(
        'corr_v', n=1, p=dim,
        testval=np.random.randn(n_elem) * std)

    corr_matrix_v = corr_triangle_v[tri_index]
    corr_matrix_v = t.fill_diagonal(corr_matrix_v, 1)
    cov_matrix_v = t.diag(sigma_v).dot(corr_matrix_v.dot(t.diag(sigma_v)))
    lambda_v = t.nlinalg.matrix_inverse(cov_matrix_v)

    mu_v = pm.Normal(
        'mu_v', mu=0, tau=beta_0 * lambda_v, shape=dim,
         testval=np.random.randn(dim) * std)
    V = pm.MvNormal(
        'V', mu=mu_v, tau=lambda_v,
        testval=np.random.randn(m, dim) * std)

    # Specify rating likelihood function
    R = pm.Normal(
        'R', mu=t.dot(U, V.T), tau=alpha * np.ones((n, m)),
        observed=train)

# `start` is the start dictionary obtained from running find_MAP for PMF.
# See the previous post for PMF code.
for key in bpmf.test_point:
    if key not in start:
        start[key] = bpmf.test_point[key]

with bpmf:
    step = pm.NUTS(scaling=start)
```

The goal with this reimplementation was to produce a model that could be estimated using the `NUTS` sampler. Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error at the last line:

```
PositiveDefiniteError: Scaling is not positive definite. Simple check failed. Diagonal contains negatives. Check indexes [   0    1    2    3    ...   1030 1031 1032 1033 1034   ]
```

I've made all the code for PMF, BPMF, and this modified BPMF available in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/macks22/00a17b1d374dfc267a9a) to make it simple to replicate the error. All you need to do is download the data (also referenced in the gist).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are passing the complete precision matrix into the normal distribution:

```
mu_u = pm.Normal(
    'mu_u', mu=0, tau=beta_0 * lambda_u, shape=dim,
     testval=np.random.randn(dim) * std)
```

I assume you only want to pass the diagonal values:

```
mu_u = pm.Normal(
    'mu_u', mu=0, tau=beta_0 * t.diag(lambda_u), shape=dim,
     testval=np.random.randn(dim) * std)
```

Does this change to `mu_u` and `mu_v` fix it for you?

Comment: Yes, that resolves the issue. I've updated the gist accordingly.